How can the button color be changed using the method
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        
        public void Chose()
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.White;
        }

        private void F03_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Chose();
        }
    }
}

I have a lot of buttons and when you click on any one it should change color. preferably through this
(it is not necessary that the button returns its color back to green when pressed again)

What's your question?  The code shown appears to be changing the color of the entire form, not a button.

You want to change the color of the clicked button, not the form's color, right? Because this.BackColor is changing the form's color.

In the F03_Click function, sender is the button you want to change.

Yes, this changes the color of the shape. I mean how to change the color of a button not through button1.BackColor = Color.White;

@user25665663: Do you mean that all buttons are using the same F03_Click event handler and you need to determine which button was clicked?

if (sender is not Button btn) return; btn.BackColor = Color.White;
